# Beginner question about String length method

Tags: java, string

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) { // Analysis and study of  String 
        String s = " Hello World ";
        s = s.length();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

In this case I know that the error is in this line of code `s = length` and I should use the variable int, `int s2 = s.length()`; what I don't quite understand is the theory behind it. Can someone explain it?

Comment: s.length return an int not a String
change s with
int nr = s.length();

Comment: Do you mean that you don't understand why variables have particular types? Or something else?

Comment: _"what I don't quite understand is the theory behind it"_ the theory behind what? Dereferencing (through `.`)? Or methods (`length()`)? Or assignment (`=`)? Or variable declaration? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Reada decent java book or tutorial. This is very basic.

Comment: @NomadMaker oh sorry i didn't know that one shouldn't ask basic questions, i'm already reading a java book but still didn't understand this part. I also tried to search for the same question on the search bar but didn't found it.  Well thanks now i know

Comment: I use the official javadocs for information,but don't have them on my system. I use ``google java String docs`` to find the documentation on String. Replace String with whatever java class you are curious about. The problem is that may not have helped you, since you were trying to assign an int to a String variable.

Comment: @NomadMaker Thanks this is a good advice. I will use the docs to know more about it. Nono everyone answers had cleared my doubt, i just wasn't clear enough with my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

`s` is of `String` data type but `length()` returns an integer of data type `int`. So it should be:

```
int any_name = s.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int length = str.length() //return type of length() is int
```